# Binary Search Through Given Lists

Tags: binary-search

. For each list below I have to say whether or not it can be a sequence of values during the search for 7..

Now I know upon some research that a binary search usually works when numbers are in an ascending or descending order and then it continues to split the list in half until you find the number you want. So if that's the case wouldn't none of these lists work because they're not in order?

Comment: Only the first list represents values looked at while performing a binary search for the number 36.  In a binary search, the data being searched must be in sequence and each new value looked at will fall between the preceding two values.  The second list fails because 92 is not between 91 and 24.  The third one fails because 62 is not between 27 and 34.

Comment: 92 could not be a valid "next found value" if the previous high was 91 and the previous low was 20.  Say the 91 was position 25 in the data list, and the 20 was position 7 in the data list, the next value you would look at would be position (7+25)/2, i.e. 16.  Position 16 will be a value lower than position 25, i.e. a value <=91, and will be a value greater than position 7, i.e. a value >=20 - so the value can't be 92.

Comment: I think everyone is getting confused because they think the numbers you have given are the original lists.  But the numbers you have given are "a sequence of values **examined** during the search for 36".

Comment: Actually - I was slightly wrong - but I included an answer which should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary search can be applied in a few different cases, for example on a tree structure where you always have two children and you need to choose one, or in a case of a sorted array of numbers where you want to quickly find a number, etc.

In the case you presented, you should indeed put that list of numbers in a sorted array, then start a binary search. The binary search is a recursive function which starts at the mid index of the array. If the number at that index is higher than the number you're looking for, then you call the function again with half that index, else if the number at that index is smaller, you recurse with half above, else it must be equal and you found the number.

That allows the array to have missing numbers in between, and you still can relatively quickly scan the array for a given number. But you must sort it first.

Hope this makes sense and helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way binary search works is by getting the leftest, lowest value, and right, largest value. Then you can do a simple calculation to get the middle point. Once you have the midpoint, you compare what you are searching for with the midpoint. If it's greater than the midpoint, then the left moves to midpoint + 1. If it is less than the midpoint, the right becomes the midpoint - 1. So the scope of what you are looking at changes depending upon that midpoint comparison. Then you recalculate to find the new midpoint and go from there until you find, or don't find, what it is you are searching for. Because of this, you would think binary search would not work on those provided list unless sorted. But...it does...

Example for the first list:

Left would be index  0
Right would be index 6
Midpoint would be the size of the list...7/2..3.5 really but things get truncated usually...so index 3 which is 24

If you were to compare what you are looking for, 36, with 24, it would be greater than. So then the left would become the midpoint + 1, which is index 4 and the new midpoint would be the index 5. The next comparison would be similar, 36 is greater than 25 so the left would become the midpoint + 1, which is the end of the list, and happens to be the number you are looking for.

So...in theory binary search only works on sorted lists but because of how 2 of the 3 lists are put together, it happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

> For each list below I have to say whether or not it can be a sequence of values examined during the search for 36

This does not mean that the lists you have been given are lists on which to **perform** a binary search.  It means that these lists are the sequence of values **examined** from some original (presumably sorted) list.

---

Assuming the original list has been correctly sorted so that a binary search is feasible, only the first list represents a valid sequence of values examined while performing a search for the number 36.

In a binary search, the data being searched must be in sequence and each new value looked at will fall between the preceding value that was less than the search value, and the preceding value that was greater than the search value.

> 92, 22, 91, 24, 89, 25, 36

In the first list, every value falls between the preceding "lower than 36" value and the preceding "higher than 36" value.

> 93, 20, 91, 24, 92, 24, 36

The second list fails at the `92` because the previous number less than `36` was `24`, and the previous number greater than `36` was `91`.  `92` is greater than `91` so is not a possible result.

> 93, 27, 34, 62, 29, 39, 35, 36

The third list fails at `29` because it is not between `34` and `62`.  (My original comment about it failing at `62` was wrong, because `62` **is** between `34` and `93`.)